# How to change color of a Error column in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a field in a SSRS table where I use a lookup function.
Sometimes I get an #Error.

I want create a font expression = **IIF ("#Error", "White", "Black")**

Why this is not working?

Comment: Click on the textbox that you want to format, get it's name from properties and then try `=IIF(ReportItems!MyTextboxName.Value = "#Error", "White", "Black")`. I've never tried this so it's just a guess.

Comment: You're best course of action is to figure out why you're getting the error and create logic to work around it so that you don't get an error. Then use similar logic to color the text box. Post your Lookup if you need help. Visual Studio should give a somewhat helpful error message when you Preview it.

Comment: I agree that is better to try fixing the error. You can also check the IsNumeric condition if you expect numeric result. In case of an error it will return false.